# MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn: recipe for target 'dkms' failed

Tags: drivers, kernel, dkms

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]
    Kernel modules: wl
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
```

UPDATE:

```
~/MT7630E$ sudo make dkms
cp -v firmware/*/* /lib/firmware/
'firmware/BT/mt76x0.bin' -> '/lib/firmware/mt76x0.bin'
'firmware/Wi-FI/MT7650E234.bin' -> '/lib/firmware/MT7650E234.bin'
cp -R . /usr/src/mt7630e-`sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*PACKAGE_VERSION=\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/p' dkms.conf`
dkms add -m mt7630e -v `sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*PACKAGE_VERSION=\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/p' dkms.conf`
Error! DKMS tree already contains: mt7630e-2.1.0
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'dkms' failed
make: *** [dkms] Error 3
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: hey thanks for help i have added the output please check.

Comment: hey try your solution but now it shows me the error i have added that please check and help.

Comment: It looks like you already installed that driver. Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: nope i have not disable secure boot.

Comment: So do it. With Secure Boot enabled you can't use any 3rd party drivers.